# Discord bot to mute everybody in voice channel not working (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want to make a bot for my discord server so it joins a voice channel I am currently in and mutes all member and unmutes them on command, like `vcmute` and `vcunmute`, but somethings missing and nothing is working. here is the code I wrote

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os


client = discord.Client()

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("myToken")


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT ACTIVATED')

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def vcmute(ctx):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in vc.members:
        await member.edit(mute=True)

@bot.command()
async def vcunmute(ctx):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in vc.members:
        await member.edit(mute=False)




bot.run("myToken")
```

Comment: The code works for me, the bot is probably missing admin permissions which prevents it from muting and unmuting members.

Comment: oh thanks that fixed it....

Comment: Great, I've posted the answer below too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me, the bot is probably missing admin permissions which prevents it from muting and unmuting members.

You could also add the [`@commands.has_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_perm#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) decorator to have it check for admin permissions, example for your code:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def vcmute(ctx):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in vc.members:
        await member.edit(mute=True)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def vcunmute(ctx):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in vc.members:
        await member.edit(mute=False)
```